# One file multiple pages?

Tags: php, html, file, get

I've seen loads of websites with one php file (or no-extension file) and multiple pages.
An example being: website.com/page.php?id=4 where the page content would be different when there's a different id number (instead of 4 - such as 7).

A real life example of this is a game site where the title and game object change as the id number changes - you can see this [here](http://www.splashworks.com/game.php?id=2) or [here](http://www.splashworks.com/game.php?id=4) :

As you can see - the game titles and game changes.

Also I'm sure you'll realise even YouTube can do this:
youtube.com/watch?v=610XM39EE1o - different video title, video, description, comments etc.
youtube.com/watch?v=LnUGl_A1cYA - different video title, video, description, comments etc.

HOW do people do this? If they use a database do they store the WHOLE html code in there (i.e. go on one of those youtube links, right click and select 'view source') - or do they assign it to another page (i.e. page.php?id=1 would retrieve content from /files/pages/1.php) - but this would be bad on storage and quite pointless, and if this is how its done, forums must be confusing if they can have something like showtopic.php?id=1701&showpost=21.

HOW is this done? Please don't request code I've tried using because I have no clue where to start!.

Thanks in advance for any answers! And sorry if this is a possible duplicate of anything - I don't understand half the language they use on answers on here anyway!

Comment: That's exactly and most likely what they're using, is a DB. However, you need to be careful when using `id=xxx`, it's best to use `mysqli_` with prepared statements or PDO should you want to further your research.

Comment: Thanks for replying! So if they're using a db - do they literally have the html code stored in there on the same row as the id (for e.g. a table with column names 'id' and 'html_code' - the first row having an id of '1', and the 'html_code' being the same as the code in a 'view source' dialog from a YouTube page (which you get by right clicking on a YouTube page and selecting 'view source') - that'd be messy wouldn't it?

Comment: The `id` in `?id=1` (*a `GET` method because of the `?` mark*) signifies that there is a column in DB named `id` and is fetching **id #1** and whatever query is made in conjunction with it, will fetch whatever other column associated with it `page_content` as an example and echo the row's content. This is far too broad a subject to further expand on, but in a nutshell, that's basically the gist of it.

Comment: The HTML that's generated doesn't always come from what's generated from DB. There could be standard HTML in any page. It depends on how the site is setup; again, too broad a subject.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have one page, or a few pages that display content within a template. The template doesn't change, but the content within the template does (corresponding to the parameters in the URL).

Pseudo code:

```
<?php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) && is_valid_id($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
if (!isset($id)) {
    // 404!
}

// get data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM forum WHERE id = $id";
// etc...
?>

// display HTML
<p>Welcome to forum: <?php echo $result['title']; ?></p>
```

There are lots of different ways to organize your files to make this easier to maintain, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

mister martin's answer is a good one, but I wanted to elaborate a little. Note that this explanation is meant to be purely conceptual - the code shown is just for illustration and should not be taken as proper, or even working, coding techniques.

The html is not stored in the database - the data that the html will contain is stored. Let's say you have a very basic blog, where each page is `myblog.php?post=id`, where `id` is some number that represents that particular blog article. In the database, you might have a table like:

```
Table: articles
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID       |    Title         |    Content                              |
======================================================================= |
| 1        | My First Article |  This is a story about...blah blah blah |
| 2        | Another Article  |  Blah blah blah story content here      |
| ...      |  ...             |  ....                                   |
| 56       | My 56th Article! |  Here is a great story about blah blah  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, you have a php page, `myblog.php`, that checks for an `id` in the url. It uses that `id` to grab the corresponding article from the database table `articles`. Let's assume we are displaying the article with `id=1`, so the url is `myblog.php?id=1`

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
    $id = $_GET['id'];
else die('No article id found!');

$query = "SELECT title, content FROM articles WHERE id = $id";
// use mysqli or pdo to execute this query, and you'll get an array with that article's data, in this example, article 1...

$data['title'] == 'My First Article';
$data['content'] == 'This is a story about...blah blah blah';
```

Then, you insert that data into the html template that is used to display any given article

```
<h1><?=$data['title']?></h1>
<p><?=$data['content']?></p>
```

So you see, every article will always have a header to display the title, `<h1>`, and an area to display the article's content, `<p>`. `myblog.php` is the same layout for every article - it has the same html and css - but it is dependent on knowing the `id` of the article you wish to display, and filling in the appropriate areas.

Comment: If you were to do this how would you maintain the address at the same time?

How would you keep the URL like:
http://www.example.com/article/1
Or
http://www.example.com/page/page

You would be still visiting http://www.example.com/index.php